Question about PNF equivalency in sub-models
I'm given this formula: $\forall x(\forall zR(x,z)\rightarrow\exists yR(y,x))$.
Now, the statement that this formula is not logically true in every sub-model of a model that makes it logically true, is true, because I can give a counter example, specifically, the model of real numbers R with the '$\leq $' relation, and the sub-model being same relation but range of natural numbers- N. But here comes the twist. I'm asked to transform the formula into it's PNF form, and asked the same question again(Wether it's also true in every sub model).
My answer is that the counter example will also be a counter example in the new context, because transformation to PNF uses logical equivalencies in the transitions, however, one of  my professors said that a PNF that starts with only $\forall $ quantifiers is equivalent in every sub model, while the other said that "A PNF that starts with a $\forall $ quantifier, followed by a $\exists $ quantifier, is not always equivalent".
I'm now very, very confused and any ray of light on the subject would be welcomed.

Try asking on math.SE
